# Devise in rails 4 doesn't show sign_in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a problem with the devise gem, I have this controller.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
  end

  def per
  end

  def po        
  end
end
```

When redirect to sign_in form , shows nothing

[sign_in form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt2DD.png)

These are my routes:

```
  match 'po' => 'admin#po', :via => :get
  match 'per' => 'admin#per', :via => :get
  match 'admin' => 'admin#index', :via => :get
  match 'admin/index' => 'admin#index', :via => :get
  match 'admin/per' => 'admin#per', :via => :get
  match 'admin/po' => 'admin#po', :via => :get       
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }      
  root 'home#index'
```

I have three templates: application, admin and home
I overwrite the default route after log in

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  #before_action :authenticate_user!
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    #request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || admin_path
    admin_path    
  end
end
```

My last gem installed:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Comment: I don't know what devise does, but my controllers use `redirect_to` to redirect instead of just putting the path helper in there as a return value.

Comment: Did you run `rails generate devise:views`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the generator for Devise views which will copy the necessary files in your `views` folder:

Run:

`rails g devise:views`

There is more information on configuring the Devise views [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably isn't with `Devise`, it looks systemic to me.

---

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   root "application#index" #-> 
   resources :model_controller, path: "", only: :index do #-> url.com/admin/...
      collection do
         get :po  #-> you shouldn't really have this
         get :per #-> you shouldn't really have this
      end
   end
end 
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

This will give you the following:

```
#app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def index
     # do something here
   end
end
```

This gives you the ability to create a custom "dashboard" type page for your admin area, from which you'll be able to use controllers bound to models.

Your `po` and `per` actions really shouldn't be there - they are not part of the [CRUD](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-first-rails-application-views-and-controllers/) system

---

In regards to your `Devise` views, the other answers *are* correct in that you would be best to [generate the `Devise` views in your app](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views):

```
rails generate devise:views
```

This won't solve your problem (hence why I downvoted the other answers). It will simply put the views in your app. It will do nothing apart from put code in a different place.

You will need to *debug* the issue:

> 1. Check the action you're seeing at `/users/sign_in`
> 2. Check the code in the `<body>` tags (which you haven't shown)
> 3. If the HTML is there, there will be some other issue preventing it from loading
> 4. If there is no HTML, it will likely mean a problem with the core of Devise

What I would recommend you do is the following:

- Generate your views
- From your screenshot, **show us the contents of the `<body>` tag**
- Screenshot your console log (this will show any errors)
- Update your question with the above

This will give you a much clearer perspective on what the potential issue will be, and allow other community members to better define the solution.